# WAV file headers reporting incorrect size

Tags: audio, wav, openal, lmms

When decoding a WAV file I'm able to read from the header the following values (formatted neatly):

```
Channels: 2
BitDepth: 16
SampleRate: 44100
FileSize: 907346
FileType: RIFF
AudioFileType: WAVE
data: [...]
PCM: 0
```

When I load this into a OpenAL buffer and attempt to play it back, the sound doesn't play. However after a lots of tweaking, I was able to get the sound to play when I hardcode the FileSize to `907300`.

This got me thinking that OpenAL most likely needs me to be offset the header when I start loading in the sample data. However a WAV file's header size is only 44 bytes. I'm also assuming that just offsetting by 46 bytes isn't really a long term solution. So where does the extra 2 bytes come from?

**Update:**

I tested another file which I downloaded of the internet instead of saving from LMMS. It doesn't play at all even after offsetting by 44 or 46 bytes. Its header is identical except for `FileSize: 1242448`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns LMMS decided it does not want to save out .wav file headers the way they are supposed to. Had a quick peek into the .wav file with dhex and the header contains unwanted info. The whole header looks like this:

```
RIFFR...WAVEfmt ........D...........LIST&...INFO
ISFT....LMMS (libsndfile-1.0.27)..data..........
```

I eventually tested with bfxr and Bosca Ceoil and all of their sounds are playing and the headers look nice a tidy.

Hope this information will be useful to someone.

Comment: LMMS *does* save .wav files properly. The problem is that it adds description section to them, which says that the file was created with LMMS or something like that. Whatever you use to parse the .wav's doesn't seem to work will that additional section. The solution would be to find a better parser or use audio editor like Audacity to edit out the description.

Comment: The point is that everything else but LMMS seems to parse fine. So I'm adding LMMS support to my parser's feature backlog. @HolyBlackCat any chance you know how to parse this LMMS wav header?

Comment: It probably works for most .wav files because most applications don't bother to write any additional info into them. Just parsing .vaw according to the spec should be enough to deal with those files.